# Having trouble starting a program with the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Tags: java, runtime, exe, actionlistener, runtime.exec

I'm currently writing a Java program that can open .exe programs on my PC, like MS Word for example.
I am having a problem though, because Runtime.getRuntime().exec() will only successfully open certain programs. I have used the exact same code for all the programs, but regardless, some programs won't open.

Here is my code for a program I downloaded, Picasa 3:

```
class picasaHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r)
    {
        try 
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Picasa3.exe");

        }
        catch (IOException t)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Sorry, could not find Picasa 3");
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, why won't Runtime.getRuntime().exec() run all the programs I use it on, and how do I run programs like Picasa 3, that I cannot run at this moment with this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that Picasa3.exe is not on your %PATH% anywhere so it doesn't know how to load it.  Have you tried specifying the full path to Picasa3.exe?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"c:\\program files (x86)\\Google\\Picasa3\\Picasa3.exe\"")
```

Comment: Well you have to put the correct path, I'm just guessing at what the path is for your machine!

Comment: code `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"h:\\program files\\Picasa\\Picasa3.exe");`

Comment: add the `\"` to the end there:  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"h:\\program files\\Picasa\\Picasa3.exe\"");` -- let me know if that helps!

Comment: Just to let you guys know, the path for my machine is `c:\program files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\Picasa3.exe`

Comment: So I input that path into my machine and it just opens the command prompt. However, when I put the path into the command prompt, Picasa opens

Comment: Well then for you it'd be `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"c:\\program files (x86)\\Google\\Picasa3\\Picasa3.exe\"");` -- Is this still not working for you?

Comment: You can test this by pasting the unescaped string into a run window: `cmd /c start "c:\program files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\Picasa3.exe"` and see if that'll run from there

Comment: No, unfortunately it just opens cmd under my java program.

Comment: Ah, try this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"c:\\program files (x86)\\Google\\Picasa3\\Picasa3.exe\"")` (remove the start command)

Answer (score 1):

```
File file=new File("picassa3");
String filename=file.getAbsolutePath(file);
try 
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename);

    }
    catch (IOException t)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Sorry, could not find the file");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime's exec can only start applications that are on the Windows path. Some programs are automatically on the path, while others, like Picasa, is not.

The only work-around for this is to determine the correct path and then launch that application.

Comment: How would I go about finding the paths that my programs are on, and would I still be able to use Runtime's exec?

Comment: Yes, you could still use the exec call if you knew the path.  The path is the location of the program executable (.exe file) on your system. I see there's already a great answer so I won't repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.
If you want to run a certain program using Runtime.exec(), just add it's installation path to path variable in your System Variables. To find it's installation path, simply right click on it's shortcut and select "Find Target". Then concat that entire address at the end of your path Variable.